# Can not import custom created class in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am importing the following class which I created like so

```js
import Select from './operations/select.js'
```

select.js

```js
export default class Select{
    constructor(db){
        this.db = db
    }

    allGenres(){
        return new Promise((res,rej)=>{
            this.db.all(`SELECT * FROM genre`,(err,rows)=>{
                if(err) res(err)
                else res(rows)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I wish to do something like

```js
return await new Select(db).allGenres()
```

But I am getting the following

```
(node:38769) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/home/lucky/workspace/web/vibe-backend/index.js:2
import Select from './operations/select.js'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1018:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1066:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1131:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:807:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

thank you for yout time.

Comment: Do as the error says and add `"type": "module"` to your package.json

Comment: Done. Now when I do "node index.js" , I get "require is not defined". I also have a couple of "require" imports and one single ES6 styled import as shown

Comment: Either go all-in on `require` or all-in on `import/export`, don't mix the two. The same could be done with `exports.Select = class Select {...}` then `const {Select} = require("./operations/select.js");`.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
const Select = require('./operations/select.js');
```